# How to extract the weekenddate date from string date?

Tags: singlestore

How can I extract the weekenddate date from a string date, e.g. `'2021-12-01'`, in SingleStore Database?

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

Use `to_date()` to convert string to date and `dayname()` to catch weekends only in `where` clause.

```
Select TO_DATE(date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from table
Where dayname(to_date(date,'YYYY-MM-DD')) in ('Saturday','Sunday');
```